# Why svn log -r head is different than svn log -l 1?

Tags: svn, logging, svn-repository

I have just made a small change ( commited that change ) to SVN in one of the scripts (being few directories deep inside SVN repo).

Now if I run

```
svn log -l 1
```

in my main directory I will not get my last change. Although if I run

```
svn log -r head
```

I will get it. What is the difference ? Why `svn log -l 1` does not limit it to the very last commit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your default revision (`-r`) checked is `BASE` (range `BASE:1`), which in this case is one or more revisions behind on `HEAD`. If you haven't updated your working directory, it does not matter the last commit is some directories down, `svn` will only know it for sure if you `svn up` that dir. If you run `svn stat -v` you can see what revision your various directories actually are.